# Best way to initialize a class from files (async)?

Tags: asynchronous, flutter, dart

I have a class I want to initialize with bunch of Strings in my flutter app. It then has to ba async. What is the best way to initialize it ?

Thanks.

Comment: You can use splash screen for like this things. Use futurebuilder and when its complete, use navigate code.

Comment: Sorry, strings are loaded from a file, so, async...

Comment: Simply load content thatbwill be displayed in my app

Answer (score 1):

Yiou can follow the following way to perform your work,

```
String str1,str2,str3;

    void main() async{
      await initialiseStrings();
      runApp(MyApp());
    } 

    initialiseStrings() async{
       // do your async work
       str1="";
       str2="";
       str3="";
    }
```

runApp() method will be called after initialiseStrings() will be executed. You can initialise the strings inside it and then you can access those strings from any class just by importing the corresponding file